# Downloading border between two countries from Open Street Map

Tags: openstreetmap

I have found many examples on how to download a country's political boundary from Open Street Map. However, I can't find any example on how to obtain the boundary between two countries.

Comment: Not sure this concept even exists in OSM datamodel, but you should be able to retrieve by intersecting the borders of 2 countries